# calling a method once the data is appended after executing the ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-5

I have an array of table names, so I need to fetch response of three tables. See the below code. Once the data is appended to the dom I need to call the successMessage method, now I am using setTimeout how can I use promise in the this scenario

```
   let lists = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3']

   lists.map(list => {
       $.ajax({
         url:`${rootUrl}/api/('${list}')`,
         type: 'GET',
         headers: {
             accept: 'application/json'
              },
         success: res => dataDisplay(res),
         error: err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
       })
    })

// displaying data
   const dataDisplay = (res) => {
    switch(res.TableName){
      case 'Table1':
       $("#tbl1 p").text(res.TableOriginalName)
       $("#tbl1 .content p").text(res.TableDescription)
       break;
      case 'Table2':
       $("#tbl2 p").text(res.TableOriginalName)
       $("#tbl2 .content p").text(res.TableDescription)
       break;
      case 'Table3':
       $("#tbl3 p").text(res.TableOriginalName)
       $("#tbl3 .content p").text(res.TableDescription)
       break;
     default:
        return
     }
 }
// successfully data appended
 const successMessage = () => alert("data appended successfully")
// calling the success method once data is appended
 setTimeout(successMessage, 3000)
```

Comment: Note: Don't use `Array#map` unless you're using its return value. To just loop through an array, use `forEach` (or [any of several other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `Promise.all` to wait for all of those requests to finish before showing the message. First, build up an array of the promises:

```
var promises = lists.map(list => $.ajax({
    url:`${rootUrl}/api/('${list}')`,
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json'
         },
    success: res => dataDisplay(res),
    error: err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
}));
```

then wait for them to complete

```
Promise.all(promises).then(() => alert("data appended successfully"));
```

You can also use `$.when` for much the same purpose, but it's awkward to call:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).done(() => ...);
```

---

In comments you've said that `dataDisplay` loads a bunch of images and you need to delay the call to `successMessage` until after those images have loaded. To do that, you'll need to watch for the `load` event on the images. This can be a bit squirrelly because the images can load before you hook the event, so we'll want to use the image's `complete` flag as well. Something along these lines:

```
Promises.all(/*...*/).then(() => {
    // Get all images in the tables we added to
    let imgs = $("#tbl1 img, #tbl2 img, #tbl3 img");

    // Hook up a function to check for completed images when we
    // see a `load` event on any of them, and fire that proactively
    imgs.on("load", checkComplete);
    checkComplete();

    function checkComplete() {
        // Count any incomplete images; remove the handler from any
        // complete image and remove it from our `imgs` set
        let incomplete = 0;
        imgs.get().forEach(img => {
            if (img.complete || img.error) {
                $(img).off("load", checkComplete);
                imgs = imgs.not(img);
            } else {
                ++incomplete;
            }
        });
        if (incomplete == 0) {
            // They're all done!
            successMessage();
       }
    }
});
```

That's off the top of my head, may need some tweaking, but it should get you headed the right way.

Comment: i need to show the message only when the dataDisplay method is completed. When i tried the solution , the message is showing first then it goes to success method of ajax call

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS: The above **does** call your final handler after `dataDisplay` is called ([proof](https://jsfiddle.net/w1x0Lhzc/2/)), it's just `alert` is getting in the way. That's one of the many good reasons not to use `alert`: It brings everything to a screeching halt, including pending UI updates. If you put your alert in a `setTimeout(..., 50)` that'll usually give the browser a chance to do its updates. Or better yet: Don't use `alert`.

Comment: @TJ Crowder: Insted of alert i have put console.log for checking, when i put break points and debug first it goes to the success then to dataDisplay three times it executes after that its going to the successMessage  method. But when i remove the break points and refresh the successMessage invokes earlier . it doesn't wait for the appending of data to dom

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS: I'm sorry, but that's simply incorrect.

Comment: @TJ Crowder: is there any solution for that one.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS: I don't know what the problem you're running into is. If you're doing the above, properly, it **isn't** that `successMessage` is being called before `dataDisplay`. It's something else. I'm sorry, I can't help you with something I can't see.

Comment: since the dataDisplay is attaching images to the dom, so the successMessage method is calling before. I will give you an update if i can reproduce the issue

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS: Again: No, it isn't being called first. It's almost certainly being called before the images are downloaded and displayed; that's a completely different thing.

Comment: @T J Crowder:so only after downloading the images and appending the entire data can i call the successMessage method

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS: That's a different question. :-) I've added to the answer above. Happy coding!

Comment: @T J Crowder: that worked like a champ !! removed the setTimeout. Thanks T J for the help. Just a small correction imgs are const so assignment wont work, please update it with let. Anyways thank you :) happy coding :)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS: Glad that helped! (And: Oops! Fixed, thanks for letting me know.)

Answer (score -1):

You may try this code:

```
let tableNames = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3']

let promiseArr = tableNames.map((table) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        $.ajax({
            url:`${rootUrl}/api/('${list}')`,
            type: 'GET',
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/json'
                 },
            success: (res) => {
                dataDisplay(res);
                resolve(table);
            },
            error: (err) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                reject(table);
            }
          });
    }).catch((e) => {
        // if call to any of the table's url fails
        // it will come here, var 'e' contains
        // that table name, handle here
         console.log(e + " has fails"); return e; 
        });
});

Promise.all(promiseArr).
    then((result) => {
        // this will run regardless of, if call to any table fails 
        console.log("success") 
    })
    .catch((result) => {
        console.log(result + " fails");
    });
```

this will asynchronously call the tables, and at the end comes to Promise.all()'s then() even if call to some table fails